# Steps to add Materialize bower package to Sage theme?

Tags: wordpress, bower, materialize, roots-sage

I'm trying to add Materialize to this [modified sage wordpress theme](https://github.com/hew/sage-lost-stylus) it is sage with bootstrap removed along with stylus and lostgrid added. [That link is repo without materialize that I'm attempting to add Materialize to.]

I've added these changes yet the materializecss and js don't seem to be available.

```
  "dependencies": {
    "materialize": "^0.97.7"
  },
  "overrides": {
    "materialize": {
      "main": [
        "./css/materialize.css",
        "./js/materialize.js"
      ]
    }
  }
```

You can see the [commit here](https://github.com/shwaydogg/sage-lost-stylus/commit/430ec161a9a6e5c8385980311f3f82288dc98427). [This is a repo with materialize added to the `bower.json`.]

What more has to be done to add a bower package to a sage theme or what am I doing wrong?

According to this [page / comment](https://discourse.roots.io/t/adding-bower-files-to-sage-8-0-0/2825/5) the only step required is what I have done in bower.json.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not seeing any Bower libraries added to your `bower.json` in the repo you linked to, so step 1 is to enter your theme dir and `$ bower install materialize --save`. Note that I performed this on a fresh install of Sage **after I removed all Bower packages and overrides** (I also commented all the `@import` directives in `main.scss` that come **after the wiredep block** to safely remove any remnants of Bootstrap's SCSS variables). If you decide to skip to the end of my answer and just use my `bower.json` file as your own then you'll just need to enter your theme dir and run `$ bower install`.

After installing Materialize via Bower you should be able to run `gulp` and see evidence of Materialize, but there are a few issues we need to resolve:

1. [The `main` property of the Materialize project](https://github.com/Dogfalo/materialize/blob/master/bower.json#L16) points to a CSS file and a minified JS file, both of these are not ideal and we will override them.
2. That first issue above also means when you load your site after running `gulp` you'll see console 404s because we need to override the fonts too.

This is the final `bower.json` file I ended up with:

```
{
  "name": "sage",
  "homepage": "https://roots.io/sage/",
  "authors": [
    "Ben Word <ben@benword.com>"
  ],
  "license": "MIT",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "materialize": "^0.97.7"
  },
  "overrides": {
    "materialize": {
      "main": [
        "./dist/js/materialize.js",
        "./sass/materialize.scss",
        "./fonts/**/*"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

You will also need to add this to your `main.scss` file **before** the wiredep block:

`$roboto-font-path: "../fonts/";`

The overrides can be improved to use just the individual SCSS components you need instead of all of them. The same goes for the JS source (although the JS files definitely need to be included in a specific order, there are a lot of them and I haven't seen a list anywhere of how they need to be ordered).

**EDIT**

If you want to include the JS files individually then I've figured out the order, just beware of dependencies if you remove anything and test thoroughly.

```
{
  "name": "sage",
  "homepage": "https://roots.io/sage/",
  "authors": [
    "Ben Word <ben@benword.com>"
  ],
  "license": "MIT",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "materialize": "^0.97.7"
  },
  "overrides": {
    "materialize": {
      "main": [
        "./js/initial.js",
        "./js/jquery.easing.1.3.js",
        "./js/animation.js",
        "./js/velocity.min.js",
        "./js/hammer.min.js",
        "./js/jquery.hammer.js",
        "./js/global.js",
        "./js/collapsible.js",
        "./js/dropdown.js",
        "./js/leanModal.js",
        "./js/materialbox.js",
        "./js/parallax.js",
        "./js/tabs.js",
        "./js/tooltip.js",
        "./js/waves.js",
        "./js/toasts.js",
        "./js/sideNav.js",
        "./js/scrollspy.js",
        "./js/forms.js",
        "./js/slider.js",
        "./js/cards.js",
        "./js/chips.js",
        "./js/pushpin.js",
        "./js/buttons.js",
        "./js/transitions.js",
        "./js/scrollFire.js",
        "./js/date_picker/picker.js",
        "./js/date_picker/picker.date.js",
        "./js/character_counter.js",
        "./js/carousel.js",
        "./sass/materialize.scss",
        "./fonts/**/*"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```